# After map function on populated array items appear to be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, return, map-function

I have a component which renders two separate tables with information. Each of the tables has its own array from which the data is extracted via "map" function and each element is turn into a table data element. The first table is displayed correctly, however, when I get to the second table, after using map function, the elements appear to be "null".

When I checked the problem in the debugger in the Mozilla Browser, what I saw was that everything was at first point fine - the array was NOT undefined, it had its elements. After that, inside the map function the "x" element was the one it should have been. All good, however, when I want to pick a particular thing from the "x" (since "x" is an object itself containing many different keys with values), for example, x.name, the "name" is undefined. So it seems that the keys were undefined. Maybe I am not storing the objects properly?

The problem appears in the DOM structure, the second table at "newShips.map".

```
return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <MDBContainer className="float-left">
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol md="6">
                        <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">Create Your Playlist</p>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
                <div>
                    <MDBTable hover>
                        <MDBTableBody>
                            {this.state.info.map(x => {
                                return <Fragment>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            {x.name}
                                        </td>
                                        <button onClick={() => this.addToList(x)}>
                                            Add To Playlist
                                            </button>
                                    </tr>
                                </Fragment>
                            })}
                            <button onClick={this.setPreviousPage} className="float-left">previous page</button>
                            <button onClick={this.setNextPage} className="float-right">next page</button>
                        </MDBTableBody>
                    </MDBTable>
                </div>
            </MDBContainer>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <MDBContainer className="float-right">
                <MDBRow>
                    <MDBCol md="6">
                        <p className="h5 text-center mb-4">My Playlist</p>
                    </MDBCol>
                </MDBRow>
                <div>
                    <MDBTable hover>
                        <MDBTableBody>
                            {newShips.map(x => {
                                return <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        {x.name}
                                    </li>
                                    <button>Remove from Playlist</button>
                                </ul>
                            })}
                            <button onClick={this.setPreviousPage} className="float-left">previous page</button>
                            <button onClick={this.setNextPage} className="float-right">next page</button>
                        </MDBTableBody>
                    </MDBTable>
                </div>
            </MDBContainer>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

What I expect to happen is to display the "name" key from the object, but if the "x" object has value, how come the "name" property is undefined?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If array is not null then try below snippet -
var self = this

(self is being used to maintain a reference to the original this even as the context is changing.)

Now,

```
                        {self.state.newShips.map(x => {
                            return <ul>
                                <li>
                                    {x.name}
                                    .
                                    .
                                    and so on
```

Hope it helps! 
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for the attempt! Sadly, after I defined it in the render method and replaced it, it showed the same result...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this morning I sorted it out! The problem was this -> after console logging the array in the browser, I noticed there was this '0" at the beginning of the Object:

```
0: Object { name: "EF76 Nebulon-B escort frigate", model: "EF76 Nebulon-B escort frigate", manufacturer: "Kuat Drive Yards", … }
```

And since the array I mapped was having many arrays inside, each one containing each separate object with this '0', I thought to myself "Maybe there has something to do with indexing". So I put a "[0]":

```
{ship[0].name}
```

And there was it - success!